# Wrong classification with Inceptionv3

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, conv-neural-network

I have used an inception model with previously trained weights and added a couple dense layers to classify horses from humans using a dataset provided by TENSORFLOW IN PRACTICE tutor Laurence Moroney.
I reckon the model has been trained perfectly but the prediction it makes is always a horse.

[image]

The image above clearly shows that accuracy is pretty good.

The code I used to upload images to colab in real time and make a prediction is given below:

```
    import numpy as np
    from google.colab import files
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    
    uploaded = files.upload()
    
    for fn in uploaded.keys():
     
      # predicting images
      path = '/content/' + fn
      img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
      x = image.img_to_array(img)
      x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    
      images = np.vstack([x])
      classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
      print(classes[0])
      if classes[0]>0.5:
        print(fn + " is a horse")
      else:
        print(fn + " is a human")
```

**Code used to train the model is given below:**

```
!wget --no-check-certificate \
  https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 \
  -O /tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5

local_weights = '/tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'

from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(include_top = False,
                                weights = None,
                                input_shape = (150, 150, 3))
pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights)

for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
print(last_layer.output_shape)
last_output = last_layer.output

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

!wget --no-check-certificate https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/horse-or-human.zip -O /tmp/horse-or-human.zip

# Get the Horse or Human Validation dataset
!wget --no-check-certificate https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/validation-horse-or-human.zip -O /tmp/validation-horse-or-human.zip 
  

import zipfile
import os

local_zip = '/tmp/horse-or-human.zip'
ref_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
ref_zip.extractall('/tmp/train')
ref_zip.close()

local_zip = '/tmp/validation-horse-or-human.zip'
ref_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
ref_zip.extractall('/tmp/validate')
ref_zip.close()

train_dir = '/tmp/train'
validate_dir = '/tmp/validate'

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   rotation_range = 0.2,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2)
training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                       target_size = (150, 150),
                                                       class_mode = 'binary',
                                                       batch_size = 64)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validate_dir,
                                                        target_size = (150, 150),
                                                        class_mode = 'binary',
                                                        batch_size = 64)

history = model.fit_generator(training_generator,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    epochs = 20,
                    verbose = 2,
                    )
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete code.

Comment: I have updated the question so check above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Main problem**: Reason is that rescaling is missing. When using image data generators rescale factor is given. However, when images are uploaded manually, the code for rescaling is missing. You have to add a `x = x/255.0`.
2. You have to use `classes<0.5`. So if probability is > 0.5 then we classify as human, not horse as you specify. You can check it with `training_generator.class_indices` and this gives you:

[image: examp]

Consider the following two examples (I take one example horse picture and one example human picture from the dataset to illustrate it):

Wrong results:

```
# predicting images
path = '/tmp/train/humans/human01-00.png'
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
# = x/255.0

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
if classes<0.5:
  print(path + " is a horse")
else:
  print(path + " is a human")
path = "/tmp/train/horses/horse01-0.png"
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
#x = x/255.0

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
if classes<0.5:
  print(path + " is a horse")
else:
  print(path + " is a human")
```

Output:

[image: ex1]

You can see that both are wrongly classified. However, wrongly classified as humans. You are wrong here, your model always predicts humans, because 1 is human and 0 is horse.

Correct results:

```
# predicting images
path = '/tmp/train/humans/human01-00.png'
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x/255.0

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
if classes<0.5:
  print(path + " is a horse")
else:
  print(path + " is a human")
path = "/tmp/train/horses/horse01-0.png"
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x/255.0

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
if classes<0.5:
  print(path + " is a horse")
else:
  print(path + " is a human")
```

Output:

[image: ex2]

So you can see it gets classified correctly.

So furthermore keep in mind that your ">" is wrong. If it is classified as 1 (>0.5) it is classified as human. Otherwise, if less 0.5 then as a horse.

(You probably got mislead by the official paper rock scissors example from the course where this is also missing in the code. It is a reported issue.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not attempted the rock paper scissors example yet but I'll keep this in mind!